# divide a parquet file into 3 parquet files using python

Tags: python, parquet

Is there a way to divide a huge parquet file into smaller ones (using Python)? Keeping all the columns and dividing rows?
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

you can do it with [dask](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/).

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

ddf = dd.read_parquet('my_file.parquet')
ddf.repartition(3).to_parquet('my_files/')
```

**edit**:
you need to install either `fastparquet` or `pyarrow`

Comment: `npartitions` isn't a valid argument, you just put `3`.

Comment: Take into account that in this case, the whole file must fit your computer's RAM

Answer (score 2):

As the answer with Dask works only for cases when the file size fits your computer's RAM, I'm going to share the script that uses Pyarrow and read the file page by page:

```
import os
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
from pyarrow import Schema


class ParquetSplitter:

    def __init__(self,
                 src_parquet_path: str,
                 target_dir: str,
                 num_chunks: int = 25
                 ):
        self._src_parquet_path = src_parquet_path
        self._target_dir = target_dir
        self._num_chunks = num_chunks

        self._src_parquet = pq.ParquetFile(
            self._src_parquet_path,
            memory_map=True,
        )

        self._total_group_num = self._src_parquet.num_row_groups
        self._schema = self._src_parquet.schema

    @property
    def num_row_groups(self):
        print(f'Total num of groups found: {self._total_group_num}')
        return self._src_parquet.num_row_groups

    @property
    def schema(self):
        return self._schema

    def read_rows(self):
        for elem in self._src_parquet.iter_batches(
                columns=['player_id', 'played_at']):
            elem: pa.RecordBatch
            print(elem.to_pydict())

    def split(self):
        for chunk_num, chunk_range in self._next_chunk_range():
            table = self._src_parquet.read_row_groups(row_groups=chunk_range)
            file_name = f'chunk_{chunk_num}.parquet'
            path = os.path.join(self._target_dir, file_name)
            print(f'Writing chunk #{chunk_num}...')
            pq.write_table(
                table=table,
                where=path,
            )

    def _next_chunk_range(self):
        upper_bound = self.num_row_groups
        
        chunk_size = upper_bound // self._num_chunks

        chunk_num = 0
        low, high = 0, chunk_size
        while low < upper_bound:
            group_range = list(range(low, high))
            
            yield chunk_num, group_range
            chunk_num += 1
            low, high = low + chunk_size, high + chunk_size
            if high > upper_bound:
                high = upper_bound

    @staticmethod
    def _get_row_hour(row: pa.RecordBatch):
        return row.to_pydict()['played_at'][0].hour


if __name__ == '__main__':
    splitter = BngParquetSplitter(
        src_parquet_path="path/to/Parquet",
        target_dir="path/to/result/dir",
        num_chunks=100,
    )
    splitter.split()
```

Also, you can use [Pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/) or [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/) Python SDK for this purpose. They allow you to split the file in a more efficient way as they can be run on a multi-node cluster. The example above uses a low-level Pyarrow library and utilizes one process on one machine, so the execution time can be big.